# Using MSAL in Linux (ubuntu based) environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to get access token using MSAL. I have received CER and PFX (no password) files. I have converted PFX to PEM which has below like content:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
[Content]
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[Content]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have uploaded the certificate (PEM file) as secure file and downloaded in my self hosted ubuntu based agent. I can access the certificate using below command:

```
$Certificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new("$env:AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY/mycert.pem")
```

However, in all the reference document for MSAL, it is recommended to use cert store path to fetch the certificate

```
$ClientCertificate = Get-Item Cert:\CurrentUser\My\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How should I use the certificate in Linux based environment where I don't have a cert store?
When I use above command to fetch the certificate and try to call get-msaltoken, it gives me "Exception calling "withcertificate" with "1" arguments: "The certificate doesn't have the private key".

Any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to configure it by adding below line post certificate download step:

```
$x509cert =    [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$Certificate
```

and it works.